# Is possible to get the content of the nth child with Cypress?

Tags: html, testing, dom, cypress

I've got an HTML code like:

```
<div class='textDiv'>
  <h1>Header 1</h1>
  <h2>Header 2.1</h2>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <h2>Header 2.2</h2>
  <h2>Header 2.3</h2>
</div>
```

Then on Cypress I've got a code like:

```
cy.get('textDiv').find('h2').then($h2 => {
  cy.log($h2[2]);
});
```

Trying to get "Header 2.3", but getting "h2" instead.

Is it possible to get the value "Header 2.3"?

Comment: seems legit, but you need the proper selector for the div cy.get('.textDiv') Maybe there is another h2 that is counting on the page or another div with that class. It is generally better to use unique selectors like ID or data-ci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this get the value you are looking for?

```
cy.get('textDiv').find('h2').then($h2 => {
  cy.log($h2[2].innerText);
});
```